# is it possible to write polygon annotation to pdf using PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pdf, annotations, polygon

I need to write polygon annotation to a pdf, using python. I've been looking at PyPDF2 library.

1. I cannot find a way to directly write in the polygon annotation
2. But I figured I could merge the pdf with a template polygon annotation pdf into one, then try to change the polygon annotation in the merged pdf to be the shape/position I wanted. I was successful in changing the vertices etc. The only problem is the initial appearance of the polygon -- which still looks what's from the template! It will refresh though with some clicks on the polygon. Something is not right.

[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIww7.png)

I wonder what's a good way to write polygon annotation to pdf with python.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has a similar question, I have a solution now --

Approach 2 above works. To get rid of the "ghost" shape, see here: 
[PyPDF2: can it update data stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142232/pypdf2-can-it-update-data-stream)